# Output channel routing

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spelevaluationexception

I am trying to rewrite Spring Integration flow from XML to Java. I would like to route data sent over a channel:

```
@Bean(name = "sendData")
public MessageChannel getSendData() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
                          .get();
}
```

into two other channels:

```
@Bean(name = "sendDataA")
public MessageChannel getSendDataA() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
                          .get();
}

@Bean(name = "sendDataB")
public MessageChannel getSendDataB() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
                          .get();
}
```

depending on their availability.

I have a `RoundRobinRouter` class that determines which output channel to use. It has a method `route` that returns output channel name, like:

```
@Component
class RoundRobinRouter {
    public String route(Object payload) {
        /* implementation */
    }
}
```

Note that `route` method implementation does not actually use the `payload` object. It was previously placed in XML configuration:

```
<int:router method="route" input-channel="sendData"
            default-output-channel="sendDataA">
    <bean
            class="com.example.RoundRobinRouter"/>
</int:router>
```

I have already tried using Java DSL `IntegrationFlow`:

```
@Bean
@ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "sendData",
                  outputChannel = "sendDataA")
public IntegrationFlow routeRoundRobin() {
    return router -> router.route(roundRobinRouter, "route");
}
```

But I was getting an error "Dispatcher has no subscribers" on `sendData.send(payload)` call, apparently caused by:

> org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException:
>   EL1004E:(pos 8): Method call: Method configure(com.example.DataType)
>   cannot be found on com.example.Integration$$Lambda$1/1018103616 type

The router is the only lambda in my Integration class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I got it to work. I'm not sure which change fixed my problem, but here's correct router implementation:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow routeRoundRobin() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(getSendData())
                           .route(roundRobinRouter, "route",
                                  r -> r.channelMapping("sendDataA",
                                                        "sendDataA")
                                        .channelMapping("sendDataB",
                                                        "sendDataB"))
                           .get();
}

@Bean(name = "sendData")
public MessageChannel getSendData() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
                          .get();
}

@Bean(name = "sendDataA")
public MessageChannel getSendDataA() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
                          .get();
}

@Bean(name = "sendDataB")
public MessageChannel getSendDataB() {
    return MessageChannels.direct()
                          .get();
}
```

I changed `@ServiceActivator` to `IntegrationFlow` from `sendData`, and also added channel mapping to the router.